# How can I set a JavaBean's property using EL?

Tags: jsp, javabeans, el

I know how to retrieve (get) a bean's properties using EL. How can I **set** a JavaBean's property using EL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A JSP is used to generate markup, from beans placed in request attributes by a controller. It shouldn't have to change bean properties. Only read from beans. So I would first check if what you're doing shouldn't be done in the controller rather than the view.

That said, to set a bean property, you use the `<c:set>` tag of the JSTL:

```
<c:set target="${someBean}" property="foo" value="someValue"/>
```